# Impersonation in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Ive been asked to fix a security issue for a webbapplication. The issue is that the webbapplication uses impersonation in the web config to log on to a domain. If the password is incorrect an exception is throwned in wich the web config credentials is shown on the screen.

Its not clear why the webbapp logs into the domain, but i need to

1. Make sure the credentials info is not shown in the exception.
2. Get the password from a database instead of storing it in web config.
3. Keep the impersonation function intact.

< system.web>

<  identity impersonate="true" userName="Domain\AdminUser" password="1234ABCD">

<  /system.web>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could encrypt your web.config file and impersonate using web.config credentials in code to control the exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
How do i get the credentials from the code? I dont need enccryption, i just need to provide the credentials in a way so they dont show with the web.config in case that an exception is thrown. Also they should be stored in a database.

Comment: Ok i give. I realize that encryption is the way to go. Problem is that im not understanding much of the tutorial on how to encrypt. Any tips?

Comment: Here is a walkthrough from MSDN which should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

Comment: I advise you to create a simple test project and go through the walkthrough with that first. That should give you an understanding of the parts that make it work.  Then apply it to your project. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should turn CustomErrors to On

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355

1. You can use programmatic impersonation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [identity element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc.aspx).

Comment: This topic is not available anymore through this link.